# How can I group by day but count for past 5 days in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, group-by

Given a table with a date column with data like

```
   2013-06-07 19:23:04.000
   2013-06-07 19:23:04.000
   2013-06-06 06:47:18.000
   2013-06-06 06:47:17.000
   2013-06-05 01:04:06.000
   2013-06-05 01:04:06.000
   2013-06-04 17:08:11.000
   2013-06-04 17:08:11.000
   2013-06-02 14:50:15.000
   2013-06-02 14:50:15.000
   2013-05-29 15:04:06.000
   2013-05-29 15:04:06.000
```

I would like to write a query that returns one row per day, and the count off all the records for that day and 3 days previous.

like this

```
2013-06-07 - 8
2013-06-06 - 6
2013-06-05 - 6
2013-06-04 - 4
2013-06-02 - 2
2013-05-29 - 2
```

A simple group by day and count (*) doesn't work as it only counts the records per day not per day and 3 days previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2013-06-07 19:23:04.000'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2013-06-07 19:23:04.000'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2013-06-06 06:47:18.000'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2013-06-06 06:47:17.000'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2013-06-05 01:04:06.000'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2013-06-05 01:04:06.000'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2013-06-04 17:08:11.000'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2013-06-04 17:08:11.000'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2013-06-02 14:50:15.000'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2013-06-02 14:50:15.000'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2013-05-29 15:04:06.000'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2013-05-29 15:04:06.000'

;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  CAST(Val AS DATE) ValDateOnly
        FROm    @Table
)

SELECT distinct ValDateOnly,
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Vals WHERE ValDateOnly BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-3,v.ValDateOnly) AND v.ValDateOnly) Cnt
FROM    Vals v
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15886)